# Read gml file in R

Tags: r, dataset, graph-modelling-language

i have problem when i try to read a gml file of [political books dataset](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/). i use the command:

```
hh=read.table("polbooks.gml")
```

> Erreur dans scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines,
>   na.strings,  :    la ligne 2 n'avait pas 2 éléments

and when i use this one:

```
library(multiplex)
hh=read.gml("polbooks.gml")
```

> Erreur dans (grep("graphics", edg, fixed = TRUE)[(i - 1)] +
>   2):(grep("graphics",  :   argument NA / NaN

i have this problem in every dataset ".gml"

Answer (score 6):

you can do like this,

```
 g<-read.graph("dolphins.gml",format=c("gml"))
```

and it's can be used for any foreign format: it's used the **igraph** package

```
 read.graph(file, format = c("edgelist", "pajek", "ncol", "lgl",
        "graphml", "dimacs", "graphdb", "gml", "dl"), ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.5 of `multiplex` solved this bug.