# Drawing graph from data in gml format in R?

Tags: r, graph, rstudio, graph-modelling-language

How to draw a graph which is in gml format (it's downloaded from facebook account) in Rstudio? Gml content looks like this:

```
    node [
        id 287
        label "Jack Daniels"
        sex "female"
        agerank 2
        wallcount 83
        locale "hr_HR"
    ]
    node [
        id 288
        label "Margaret Grey"
        sex "male"
        agerank 1
        wallcount 1
        locale "en_GB"
    ]
    edge [
        source 0
        target 9
    ]
    edge [
        source 1
        target 5
    ]
```

Comment: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/UCINET

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read gml file in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964898/read-gml-file-in-r)